# Bytea hex to decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function in vendor's PostgreSQL 9.6.4, which returns `SETOF "Values"` (I don't see this type in `\dT`'s output), example:

```
select "Data" from getlastvaluesnamed((E'341d0b24-...')::uuid,(E'G1')::text);
  Data
--------
 \x0015
```

I wan to receive this in decimal, so tried dozen of requests like this:

```
select "Data"::int from getlastvaluesnamed(...);
ERROR:  cannot cast type bytea to integer

select "Data"::text::int from getlastvaluesnamed(...);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "\x0015"


select to_number('123', "Data"::text) from getlastvaluesnamed(...);
 to_number
-----------
         3  << -- Wrong, should be 21

select encode("Data"::bytea, 'hex')::int from getlastvaluesnamed(...));
 encode
--------
     15     << -- Wrong, should be 21
```

and so on.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bytea value is always 4 digits:

```sql
select concat('x', encode('\x0015'::bytea, 'hex'))::bit(16)::int;
```

Otherwise, for values with less than 9 digits:

```sql
select concat('x', lpad(encode('\x0015'::bytea, 'hex'), 8, '0'))::bit(32)::int;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/lpjndfRw)